# reCAPTCHA error: your site currently using reCAPTCHA v1, but code version is 2 for shure

Tags: recaptcha

We envolved reCaptcha code to our forum
http://www.citycardriving.com/component/user/register
but now have error:

> Your site is currently using reCAPTCHA v1, which will be turned off on
>   March 31, 2018. Please, see our developer site for more information

But we initially created captcha as V2.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH0F8.png)
How can it be?

Comment: I don't get any errors in my Chrome console about reCAPTCHA.

Comment: The error shows up in the admin console (google.com/recaptcha/admin) ... not for users to the site in question. And yes, that error message is confusing and non-helpful given a site is using v2, but it alerts otherwise.